# Delete an email from a folder only if it is not contained in another folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I was searching around but found no answers about this issue: I have a folder, in my Gmail account, where I automatically (with filters) put mail with attachments and other characteristics... they are basically emails that could be deleted. I periodically delete all emails form such folder.

However, **some** of them, which have also additional labels, are useful to me and I don't want to delete.

Is there a way of deleting all emails from a folder **except** the ones which also belong to other folders?

Another way of considering the question: is there a way to delete all messages marked with a certain label **only** and not with other labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with a filter, because those act when the message comes in. However, it's simple to do with a search.

```
label:first -label:second
```

That search string will return all conversations with the label `first` and **do not** have the label `second`. The minus sign (`-` or hyphen, if you prefer) means negation.

More information about search operators is available at [Advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

If you want to exclude more labels, simply add them to your search string:

```
label:first -label:second -label:third
```

Comment: Many thanks, it partially fix the problem but it can work. The more comprehensive solutions would be to find  a way to exclude 'all other labels' without having to specify them all. In my case I have many labels and writing `-label:second -label:third ...-thirteenth..` would be a bit annoyng

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's just how it works right now.